# Network disappears from list, disconnects, others remain

Tags: wireless, networking, dual-boot, network-manager, ethernet

and Ubuntu, with my first question.

I have Ubuntu installed on three machines alongside Win7, so they are all dual boot. I have encountered a WiFi connection problem on one, a Compaq CQ62.

The unit boots perfectly fine. It connects to my WiFi network. Shortly thereafter, it disconnects from the network and the network, itself, disappears from the WiFi connections list.

Does this appear to be a common issue? I'm thinking if I connect to the ethernet line, a software update would come in for recent updates, but would like to see what folks may have to offer.

Thank you.

Comment: If your machine has a Realtek wireless card, [the fixes listed here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2264505) might fix your issue. If not, run [this script from the Ubuntu wireless forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108) and post the results up with your question; someone should be able to help you.